# How create style on websphere portal 7 based on theme

Tags: css, styles, themes, portal, websphere-portal

We are using Websphere Portal 7 and I need to create a new style based on Theme which is working, only need this style for one page and I'm very new on websphere portal.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is this a Web2 theme, PageBuilder2 Theme, or legacy theme style?

Comment: I solved my problem, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this doing a check based on the page id, I just needed modify the default.jsp page from Skin deployed. This works for my side.

```
<% boolean mobileLogin = false; %>
<portal-logic:if selection="EXAMPLE.PublicArea.myMobilePage">
<style>
    .section-mobile {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    }
.login{margin:0 auto;}</style>
<div class="section-mobile">
<img src="/Theme/themes/html/MyTheme/img/logo.gif" class="logo-mobile">
<c:if test="${!renderPlaceholdersOnly}">
                            <portal-core:screenRender/>
                        </c:if>
<% mobileLogin = true; %>
</div>
</portal-logic:if>

<% if (mobileLogin != true){
%>
```